# I was wondering if anyone knew what the 3 axis on an accelerometer are?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am trying to create an algorithm to record data from a accelerometer, I was wondering if anyone knew what the x,y and z axis values were exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the [Sensors Overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html):

> Measures the acceleration force in m/s^2 that is applied to a device on
>   all three physical axes (x, y, and z), including the force of gravity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not that I can go into too much detail but can give you some insight.

The accelerometer measures forces made on the mobile, so if you put the phone on the table it should output `x=0, y=1, z=0` (depending on which way the device is facing). The reason for this is that the table applies force to the phone keeping it from falling to the ground. As a consequence a reading of all zeroes would imply free-fall.

This means that often one of the first tasks when gathering accelerometer data is to determine which axis (or combination of) reads the forces of gravity and thereby knowing which part of the phone is facing up.

This guy explains it rather well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZVgKu6v808

Hope this is clear enough, otherwise attend to the documentation as mharper suggests.